# How to get group by results in sitecore sxa search results component

Tags: sxa

1. I Have a locations page with 3 filters, country, state and brand
2. Even markup also has group by structure, need to show all locations under each country title.

My question:

How to apply group by for search results in SXA 10.1.

How can I write my own markup for search results.

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: It would be great if you could put more effort describing the challenge, because I cannot understand it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi Alan,

1. I have a Location template which has fields a. Country b. State c. City droplist fields

2. Need to build locations overview page contains a. Three filters b. List of location with pagination.

3. Added search components search results, dropdown filters and added custom fields to solr default index field mapping.

4. Able to get values in dropdown and also seeing results
5. Issue coming with my display markup, where as i need to show country name and all locations, like below. How to render like below

India
    Hyderabad
    Mumbai
USA
    Alabama
    Alaska